# How to setup Facebook Timeline Cover Photo auto upload in website?

Tags: facebook-timeline, cover, photo-upload

I am new to Facebook API and app development. I am trying to build a facebook timeline cover website where users can auto upload and publish the cover to a new album created in the website/app name. Then they would be redirected to another page on my website with instructions on how to setup the cover on their profile timeline. Most profile cover websites are using the same method such as myfbcovers.com, facebookprofilecovers.com, profilephotocovers.com, facebook.coversdaddy.com, fbcoverlover.com and newfbcovers.com to name a few. I have been searching the facebook developer pages and several tutorials over the net. Some tutorials I checked are:

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/

http://daipratt.co.uk/facebook-api-upload-photo/

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

And also several youtube videos.

But there are several confusions I have about the app. Sorry for the questions if they are too basic as I am a complete newbie who is willing to learn. One of the main problems is that most of the tutorials are outdated as the facebook app creation page etc. Now is different and there is no callback url etc. or canvas etc. in options now which are used in the tutorials. In the tutorials, it is mentioned that for creating a website app or facebook app for page, I need a callback URL which I cannot see now. Secondly, if it is mentioned in those tutorials that I need SSL in my website for an app but none of the facebook cover websites listed above have SSL it seems. I also do not have SSL on my server. So, not sure if that is needed and if an app is needed at all on my local server. And all the apps are doing things different such as I can see these URLs on clicking on some of the clickable links for uploading the cover button. Here are a few examples:

http://facebookprofilecovers.com/wp-content/themes/fbcovers/fb/?i=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebookprofilecovers.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2FHappily-Married-Facebook-Timeline-Cover.png

http://freetimelinecovers.net/facebook/?cov_img=/images/sports-covers/manchester-united.jpg

Some have direct link to the facebook app page such as:

<strike>http://apps.facebook.com/profilephotocovers/index.php?id=35</strike>  *broken link*

And only one website seems to have the publish_stream etc. in the url itself

https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=162046520556852&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.coversdaddy.com%2Fi-m-not-a-monster-1242.html&state=e4abcdc1d9288be8233a7ac4aa243997&scope=user_photos%2Cpublish_stream

On checking through Live HTTP header, it seems all websites are following a similar pattern which is directly used in the URL in the last website. For example, here are a few steps of the other websites I saw while checking with Live HTTP header.

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=112308188876405&redirect_uri=http://www.myfbcovers.com/oauth/callback&scope=publish_stream,user_photos,email

https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=237897089598589&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebookprofilecovers.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Ffbcovers%2Ffb%2Findex.php&state=0ca1581f006bdd80bd5da78e95179f3a&scope=publish_stream

And so on.

I could also notice that almost all websites were taking auth for only publish_stream and nothing else. Only myfbcovers.com is an exception which also asks for user_photos and email. Rest are not asking for the same and so perhaps publish_stream is the only permission needed.

So, to create the app is there any tutorial. And do I need to host the app on my own server in a sub directory of the website or does it make direct call to facebook. The reason I am asking is because it seems Facebook apps if hosted on local server needs SSL mandatory whereas none of the above websites have SSL/https. And if I do not need to host the app on my own server then how can I make the photo upload link to facebook and then return back to the website for the rest of the instructions. I am using Wordpress on my website like most of the other sites are doing and so, that should not be a problem I suppose. Any help would be highly appreciated. I am willing to learn properly and some good tutorials for creating the photo album and then uploading the photo to the user's album etc. would be fine too if not with the full code. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**NOTE:** I have removed the HTTP and WWW part in many of the above URLs as I can only post a maximum of two links being a new user. Please add them if needed in those where they are not present.

Comment: Your question is a bit long.  You should focus on some of the problems and not all at the same time - i'd say start with authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I did not install all the applications above to see exactly what they did.  I think your question is long... but pretty straight forward.  This is what I understand your question to be : 
You would like to create a cover photo generator that will allow users to customize their cover photo by uploading files, maybe doing some editing to them. Also maybe using templates of cool ideas and in the end being able to update their cool new cover photo directly into their profile.

This is not very complicated to do although to this date there is no real documentation (by facebook) about how to dynamically update the cover photo.  However there are ways of [creating photo albums and uploading photos to there](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498).

**If you are planning to make your application run with in facebook - that means use the `apps.facebook.com/your_app_name`, and have canvas or tab URLS, then [you will have to purchase an SSL certificate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/).**
Finnaly, in order to get as close to the functionality your want, you might have to make some sacrifices (becuase changing the cover photo is not possible **yet** with the Graph API).  
To locate the cover photo album you'll have to manually scan through all the users albums names - and for that you'll need the `user_photos` permission.
Once you have created the photo you want, you could possibly let the user upload it (`publish_stream` permission needed for this) to a different album, and then give the user some detailed instructions using screen shots and direct them exactly how to change their cover photo.
I recommend you read through the [Authentication documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) decide what [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) you need (such as `user_photos` for the users photos and `publish_stream` for uploading a new picture or creating an album.)
In addition, there are many many tutorials on the [Official Facebook Documentation Pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) and their [Developers Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/)- check them out before going onto other sites that have written their own tutorials.  Facebook does update their API quite a bit - but they also (recently) have been pretty good on updating their documentation to mirror the changes to the API...

---

As serious developers using a 3rd party API (
Graph API ), it is solely our responsibility to keep up to date with changes and to write code and applications that comply with their platform policies.